# Lua: pcall() doesn't work with coroutine as expected

Tags: error-handling, lua, coroutine

```
local function proc_close(a, b)
    _XNO.processList[a] = nil
    if b then panic("process, "..b) end
end

local function proc_load(a)
    local thread = coroutine.create(function()
        os.execute(a)
    end)
    _XNO.processList[thread] = a
    local status, err = pcall(coroutine.resume, thread)
    if not status then
        proc_close(thread, err)
    end
end

proc_load("/some_file")
```

When it gets to error in executed file pcall() does nothing, error returned as it would be in main code. There is no difference if I pcall() the function in coroutine, or I pcall() the coroutine itself. How Can I catch the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pcall` does nothing because no error is raised: an error in the executed file does not raise an error in the caller of `os.execute`.  You need to test the return code of `os.execute` and raise an error if you want.

Comment: You right! I forgot that already had this mistake and feel like a dummy now. Replacing it with `dofile()` worked.

Answer (score 2):

Two issues: (1) `os.execute` doesn't throw any errors when it fails to execute a command, it returns `nil` and reports the error, so "resume" completes successfully, (2) you don't need `pcall`, as `resume` call already does what's needed to capture the error. Try on the following example:

```
local thread = coroutine.create(function()
    foo()
  end)
print(coroutine.resume(thread))
```

This prints `false  pcall-thread.lua:2: attempt to call global 'foo' (a nil value)` for me.